# Proof of Identities

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find the values of $a,b,c \text{ and } d$ so that the following equation is an identity.

$$x^3+1=a(x-1)^3+b(x-1)^2+c(x-1)+d$$

I tried using this way which is :

say $(x-1)=y$:

then $a(y)^3+b(y)^2+c(y)+d$ ,
but i am kind of lost as of now .

Comment: So $x=y+1$ and you get $(y+1)^3+1=ay^3+by^2+cy+d$. Can you find $a,\ldots,d$ now?

Answer (score 3):

Option:

LHS:

$((x-1)+1)^3+1=$

$((x-1)^3+3(x-1)^2 +3(x-1) +1)+1$

Compare coefficients of powers of $(x-1)$ with RHS.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The easiest way is to expand the right-hand side using the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Expand $(x-1)^{2}$ and $(x-1)^{3}$ and equate coefficients of like powers of $x$. This gives $a=1, b-3a=0, 3a-2b+c=0$ and $1=-a+b-c+d$. From these you get $a=1, b=3, c=3$ and $d=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Taylor series about $x=1$.

Setting $f(x)=x^3+1$, we have $f(1)=2$, $f'(1)=3$, $f''(1)=6$ and $f'''(1)=6$, therefore $$x^3+1 = \frac6{3!}(x-1)^3+\frac6{2!}(x-1)^2+3(x-1)+2.$$